# End-to-end correlation of polymers not decorrelating

Tags: statistical-thermodynamics, monte-carlo, polymers

I am running Monte Carlo simulations of polymers with nearest neighbor interactions only. For benchmarking purposes, I decided to run some excluded volume simulations (no overlaps) allowed on a 3D simple cubic lattice (coordination number of 6).

These are the moves I implemented:
[image]

The problem I am seeing is that the end-to-end autocorrelation function for my single polymer is not dying down to zero. The reason I call this a problem because I am getting incorrect Flory Exponents:
$$\langle R_g^2\rangle \propto N^{2\nu}, \tag{1}$$
where I am getting $\nu = 0.8$, which is too high.

I am running 10^7 steps with Rosenbluth sampling.

E.g. If there are N possible kink jump spots, I will test each spot until there is a vacancy available. Same applies for the end rotations.

What could be the cause of this? Is it simply that my moves are too local? How do I decorrelate my system faster, as N increases?

Comment: Just to clarify, how close is the autocorrelation function getting to zero? What (roughly) are you expecting the Flory exponents to be?

Comment: From renormalization group theory, I expect $\nu$ to be 0.33 in bad solvent, and 0.6 in a solvent with only excluded volume interactions -- and higher if solvent quality increases further. But when I run simulations at a T=0.5, my scaling exponent hits 0.37 for bad solvent.

Comment: As for the exact value of the auto-correlation function, it either stays very non-zero (0.2-0.4), or oscillates more wildly than expected

Comment: Did you figure this out now? Please update us!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this moveset is that it is too local. The best way to decorrelate polymer configurations is to run simulations with more aggressive moves, such as chain regrowth.